# How to keep footnotes to the bottom of the page with \sloppybottom in memoir?

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, memoir

I am using the the `memoir` class to typeset a book, where the text has many footnotes. To avoid widows and orphans I use the option `\sloppybottom`. That has the result of under full pages. `memoir` normally sets the empty space of these under full lines at the very bottom of the page. But I would like this space to be between the text block and the footnotes. I did not found any solution for that in the documentation for the memoir class.

So I found the package `fnpos`. This packages seems to do exactly what I need, but I was wandering if there is a `memoir` way to do this. Or if it is recommended to use `memoir` with this package.

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
% This package sets the footnotes to the bottom, but isn't there a 
% method to do this with memoir?
\usepackage{fnpos}

\setstocksize{23.5cm}{15.5cm} 
\settrimmedsize{23.5cm}{15.5cm}{*}
\setulmargins{2.25cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.25cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.25cm}{2.25cm}{*}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}

\setheaderspaces{*}{1.2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\clubpenalty=5000
\widowpenalty=5000
\displaywidowpenalty=5000

\sloppybottom

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
\footmarkstyle{\textsuperscript{#1}\hfill}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.5em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1.6\onelineskip}

\begin{document}
\midsloppy
\frontmatter 
\mainmatter
\chapter[]{This is the title of the Test}

\blindtext
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec
ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue,
a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies
vel, semper in, velit. U
Lorem lis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue,
a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies
vel, semper in, velit. U\footnote{\blindtext}


\section{A section nothing else}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\footnote{\blindtext} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec
ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue,
a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies
vel, semper in, velit. U \blindtext


\end{document}
```

As mentioned in the comments, there is the option `\feetbelowfloat` in the `memoir` class. But it does not work. Does anybody know why? It seems that this was a bug that was [reported 2010](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/IMmfenKujoI). I prefer the package `\usepackage{fnpos}` because with `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` I can't use the `memoir` way to set other footnote options.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` (which is to be preferred over `fnpos` in my opinion), but it is possible to do it 'by hand' if you need to.  And in fact, `memoir` does have a command `\feetbelowfloat`, which *should* work as you wish, but does not always do so in my experience.  There is a post to that effect on `comp.text.tex` from a few years ago

Comment: Could you please add minimum working example in your post? It would help solvers a lot.

Comment: @Malipivo I added a working example.

Comment: @user5950 that is not a working example. We do not have `chapter/Test.tex`

Comment: @daleif Sorry, I corrected this.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? When I compile this the footnotes are at the bottom of the page. I'm using `memoir 2013/05/30 v3.7b`

Comment: @daleif The package `fnpos` does that. But my question is, whether or not there is a way to achieve that goal with `memoir` only.

Comment: I'll have to see what fnpos does

Comment: @daleif You just have to comment it out.

Comment: Better late then never, `\feetatbottom` feature is added to the text `memoir` release. Adopted from `footmisc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since memoir v3.7e it is possible to set the footnotes to the bottom of the page, with:

```
\feetatbottom
```

> Then we use `\raggedbottom` or similar, L A TEX will by default attach
>   the footnotes just below the text. In many cases it may look better if
>   the footnotes are being build from the bottom of the texst block up.
>   Issuing `\feetatbottom` does this. Please note that `\feetatbottom` has no
>   effect whenever `\flushbottom` is active.

[[Memoir manual](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf), p. 12]

Comment: Memoir manual link is incorrect (points at `microtype` package) and is dead as of late 2018.  [Current memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) seems to say nothing about `\feetatbottom`.  [The `memoir` README file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/README) does mention it added in version 3.7d, however.