# Avoid underfull \vbox with page number "inside textblock"

Tags: footnotes, memoir, boxes, warnings, thesis

My thesis requirements state that the page numbers must be "centered at one inch from the bottom of the page." All the margins are to be 1 inch and nothing can be printed in the margin area.

I have tried to do this by subtracting the height of the footnote from the `\textheight`. But I am getting `Underfull \vbox` warnings on almost every page.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\DoubleSpacing
\flushbottom

\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*} % 1 inch margins on both sides
\setlength{\uppermargin}{1in}
\setlength{\footskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setlength{\lowermargin}{1in}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\uppermargin}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\lowermargin}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}
\lipsum[5]\footnote{\lipsum[6]}

\lipsum[7]\footnote{\lipsum[8]}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\lipsum[5]\footnote{\lipsum[6]}

\lipsum[7]\footnote{\lipsum[8]}

\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need `\flushbottom`? Removing it the warning disappears.

Comment: Hmmm, this seems easy enough using `\geometry{margin=1in,includeheadfoot}` with [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: @Werner If I replace the layout adjustment block in the MWE with your suggestion, I get even more warnings. `Memoir` and `geometry` don't get along well.

Comment: @karlkoeller In the end I may have to do that, and I doubt anyone but me would care. But I wanted to know if this was possible with \flushbottom.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: You minimal example only shows this problem on page four. It's certainly to do with using `\flushbottom`. Using `\raggedbottom` (perhaps the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) default) should solve the problem. It's also common to experience this type of problem when dealing with an increased line spacing.

Comment: Why are you using `\flushbottom` in the first place? It is already the `memoir` default. If I remove it and recompile, AFAICS I get exactly the same, and no `\vbox` stuff.

Comment: @daleif memman p. 5: "When the twoside or twocolumn option is selected then typesetting is done with \flushbottom, otherwise it is done with \raggedbottom." The example uses the`oneside` option, so it would use `\raggedbottom` by default.

Comment: @Werner You're right, I think this is a combination of increased line spacing plus a lot of large tables and figures in the real document. I suppose it's not worth the effort to make it `\flushbottom`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, you're right, I usually never use oneside for larger documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `\flushbottom` (that is, with `\raggedbottom` selected instead by default), this page layout works fine without any warnings.

By default `memoir` uses `\raggedbottom` for documents with the `oneside` option. I realize now that one of the main reasons for using `\flushbottom` is to align text on facing pages of a `twoside` document. So it really doesn't make sense to do `\flushbottom` in this case, especially for a research document.

Thank you to @karlkoeller, @Werner, and @daleif for setting me straight.

**EDIT**

Thanks to this question ([How to keep footnotes to the bottom of the page with \sloppybottom in memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170865/how-to-keep-footnotes-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-with-sloppybottom-in-memoir)), I discovered I can use the package `fnpos` with its default options to keep all footnotes at the bottom of the page. So the extra space added on the `\raggedbottom` pages gets added above the footnotes instead of below. This greatly improves the page appearance, in my opinion.

Comment: It is on my todo list for `memoir`, but when I get to it is unknown.

Comment: @daleif I'm sorry, I didn't realize you were the package maintainer. Which thing is on your todo list?

Comment: The footnote always at the bottom part. It has already been requested.

Comment: @daleif Super! I look forward to it.