# How to position a figure enviroment above footnote?

Tags: graphics, floats, environments, footnotes, memoir

It's a simple question: I'd like to put figure on the bottom of the page, but above footnote. I'm using *memoir*, but with *documentclass{article}* the result is the same.

Example:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{The footnote}

\begin{figure}[b]
\vspace{2cm}
\caption{Bild 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I don't want to use a process of trial and error for each figure in my document, "hacking" the position option with an *[h]*.

Comment: Removing `[b]` could help ;-) You could drop the `figure` environment and use `\captionof{figure}{Bild 2}` instead. (Needs `caption` package)

Comment: one could use `Some text\footnote{The footnote}
\vfill
\begin{figure}[h]`

Comment: To me this behavior seems to be a bug in float positioning. I don't know if exist some fix for this miss positioning beside manual tweaking for each case separately. What is not big problem, if such occasions are very rare in document.

Comment: `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` or (only in memoir) `\feetbelowfloat`

Comment: Related: [Tables below footnotes, is this a good output routine algorithm or a bug?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32951/5764)

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [How do I force footnotes to the very bottom of the page when the page is not full?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3527504/914686)

Comment: The solution proposed by @UlrikeFischer works. But is there a way doing so without have to resort to another package? I tried use the memoir `\feetatbottom` but without success.

Comment: I wrote `\feetbelowfloat` not `\feetatbottom`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to keep footnotes to the bottom of the page with `\sloppybottom` in `memoir`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170865/5764)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` or (only in memoir) the command `\feetbelowfloat`.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\feetbelowfloat
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{The footnote}

\begin{figure}[b]
\vspace{2cm}
\caption{Bild 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]