# Position a figure above the footnote in xepersian

Tags: floats, footnotes, xepersian

I am using LaTeX + `xepersian` for writing my thesis. I have so many figures and so many footnotes. For footnote, I am using `\LTRfootnote{}`. Unfortunately, when I use the following environment for a figure, the figure is placed below the footnote:

```latex
\begin{figure}[b]
....
\end{figure}
```

How can I position the figure above the footnote?

PS. I checked the [How to position a figure environment above footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324415/how-to-position-a-figure-enviroment-above-footnote/324719). But, using the package `footmisc` doesn't change anything for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures,localise]{xepersian}

\begin{document}

در این بخش درباره سیب \LTRfootnote{apple} صحبت میکنیم.

\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics{...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @SalimBou, I added an example in the question. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `float` package with `H` option.
**Your codes:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures,localise]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
در این بخش درباره سیب
\LTRfootnote{apple} 
 صحبت می‌کنیم.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{...}
\caption{زیرنویس}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And your `output`:

[image]

**Second edition:**
If you want to be your figure above the footnote (at the bottom of the page) use this codes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures,localise]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
در این بخش درباره سیب
\LTRfootnote{apple} 
 صحبت می‌کنیم.
متن را می‌توانید در اینجا وارد کنید.
\null\vfill
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{...}
\caption{زیرنویس}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Good luck

Comment: I want to put the figure at the bottom of the page! I edited your code as the following 
```
\begin{document}
در این بخش درباره سیب
\LTRfootnote{apple} 
 صحبت می‌کنیم.

\begin{figure}[bH]
\centering
\includegraphics{Figures/Ch4/shapeSpaceN1.jpg}
\caption{زیرنویس}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```
Unfortunately, it doesn't work!

Comment: @Venus Please see the second edition.